# Tor - dependency/package error on debian wheezy

Tags: linux, debian, apt-get, tor

When I am trying to install Tor on Debian wheezy via Apt-Get CLI, I am getting the below error. Libevent and LibSSl are already installed on the system. Do you have any suggestions on how to resolve this?

```
# apt-get install tor
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
tor : Depends: libevent-1.4-2 (>= 1.4.13-stable) but it is not installable
   Depends: libssl0.9.8 (>= 0.9.8k-1) but it is not installable
   Recommends: tor-geoipdb but it is not going to be installed
   Recommends: torsocks but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: I sthis a clean wheezy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a standard Wheezy, fully updated. On my system,

```
   apt-cache show tor
```

displays, among other things:

```
 Depends: libc6 (>= 2.10), libevent-2.0-5 (>= 2.0.10-stable), libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.1), zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4), adduser, lsb-base
```

Thus *libevent* and *libssl*  of a perfectly updated Wheezy are much later than the versions displayed by your version of the package. Thus I suspect you have some newer versions of both libevent and libssl, which is why you cannot install the versions relative to this package, but some older version of some other package which prevents installing a newer version of *tor*.

I would suggest first running an update+dist-upgrade, and after this, if the installation of the package is still impossible, checking the current versions of the offending dependencies against the required ones.

Alternatively, you may try to see whether you can install *tor* directly from the tor site repos. You can find full instructions (quite simple, really) [here](https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en).

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following entry in /etc/apt/sources.list or a new file in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/:

```
deb http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org trusty main
deb-src http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org trusty main
```

Then add the gpg key used to sign the packages by running the following commands at your command prompt:

```
gpg --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv 886DDD89
gpg --export A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89 | sudo apt-key add -
```

You can install it with the following commands:

```
$ apt-get update
$ apt-get install tor deb.torproject.org-keyring
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind if your using the latest version of Ubuntu you need to use the code name that you list in the /etc/apt/sources.list

So in my /etc/apt/sources.list since I am running bionic-security I used the following:

deb https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org bionic-security main
deb-src https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org bionic-security main

Answer (score 0):

I received the same issues after following the instructions on the tor project site. I initially only edited /etc/apt/sources.list file, but to solve the issue I included the lines:

```
deb http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org trusty main
deb-src http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org trusty main
```

To **both files:**

```
/etc/apt/sources.list
```

**AND**

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list
```

Then continue with the rest of the install from repository instructions:

```
gpg --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89
gpg --export A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89 | sudo apt-key add -

$ apt-get update
$ apt-get install tor deb.torproject.org-keyring
```

I hope that helps.